# css - div boxes are shaking on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I've a problem with css - I want to have 0.3s smooth transition of a div on hover and other divs to stay as it is. divs are in line and whenever I hover on right side(2,4,6 - in jsfiddle) of the div, next row divs are shaking. I've tried and referred many sites to fix it. Could you please help me with this.

This code is working fine on safari. But, not on other browsers.

```css
#datelist {
  background-color: white;
  width: calc(80% - 25px);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7.5px 0px 7.5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7.5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.displaydate {
  width: calc(50% - 32px);
  height: 35vw;
  background-color: #fafeff;
  color: #05336D;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 9;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px #bce6fb solid;
  border-radius: 0.75vw;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.displaydate:hover {
  background-color: #00AADC;
  color: white;
  border-color: #00AADC;
  width: calc(50% - 12px);
  height: calc(35vw + 20px);
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: inherit;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 1.15vw;
  box-shadow: 0px 7.5px 7.5px #93AAB6;
}
```

```html
<div id="datelist">
  <div class="displaydate">1</div>
  <div class="displaydate">2</div>
  <div class="displaydate">3</div>
  <div class="displaydate">4</div>
  <div class="displaydate">5</div>
  <div class="displaydate">6</div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Arocki

Comment: Why not use this CSS on hover: transform: scale(1.1);

Comment: Changing the size on hover causes the element to move out from under the cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `display: inline-block` and `float: left` at the same time. It will only mess things up.

I will also strongly recommend you to use `* { border-box: box-sizing; }` when working with paddings. That will help you a lot.

Also. When you a using inline-block, I would advise you to use `vertical-align: top`, so the elements always are aligning perfectly.

So to fix your problem; remove `float: left` and add the above code. Then it should work.

I've modified your existing code, so it now works like intended.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#datelist {
  background-color: white;
  width: calc(80% - 25px);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7.5px 0px 7.5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7.5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.displaydate {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 32px);
  height: 35vw;
  background-color: #fafeff;
  color: #05336D;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  z-index: 9;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px #bce6fb solid;
  border-radius: 0.75vw;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.displaydate:hover {
  background-color: #00AADC;
  color: white;
  border-color: #00AADC;
  width: calc(50% - 12px);
  height: calc(35vw + 20px);
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: inherit;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 1.15vw;
  box-shadow: 0px 7.5px 7.5px #93AAB6;
}
```

```html
<div id="datelist">
  <div class="displaydate">1</div>
  <div class="displaydate">2</div>
  <div class="displaydate">3</div>
  <div class="displaydate">4</div>
  <div class="displaydate">5</div>
  <div class="displaydate">6</div>
</div>
```